# PHP fetch MySQL array with an index

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

When fetching an array from MySQL the rows are typically returned with a key from 0 to the size of your recordset:

```
row[0][key][value]
```

Is it possible to have one of the fields from the select statement returned as the key in the array?

For example.  Assuming my data set has StudentID, Name, City, etc.

How can I select into an array where I could refer to the StudentID as the index like this:

```
rows[StudentID][Name]
rows[StudentID][City]
etc.
```

Thanks!

Comment: you should post some code instead of writing "When fetching an array..."

Comment: Then he'll post code about using `mysql_*` :(((((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

> To return an associative array grouped by the values of a specified column, bitwise-OR PDO::FETCH_COLUMN with PDO::FETCH_GROUP.

```
// Other PDO stuff to get a statement - abstract below
$result = PDOStatement::fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_COLUMN | PDO::FETCH_GROUP, 0 );
```

See example 3 on [this page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: This works, but not as needed, when e.g. column 0 is an (unique) ID like here StudentID. Then you'll always get an "extra" index 0 level, like e.g. StudentID=4: `ARRAY(4=>ARRAY(0=>ARRAY('StudendID'=>4, 'StudendName'=>'Joe', ...)))`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which library you are using:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc()

mysqli_fetch_assoc()
```

PDO fetches both by default.

Comment: He wants the first column to the the array key of the result set.

Comment: @Kevin Peno Oh, that wasn't entirely obvious from the original version of this question. Sorry.

Comment: @ Kevin Peno No offense taken, either. Thanks. :)